# Compile specific tests into binary

Tags: unit-testing, testing, rust, rust-cargo

I would like to compile a binary which runs a certain subset of tests. When I run the following, it works:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:/ox$ cargo test hash::vec
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.11 secs
     Running target/debug/deps/ox-824a031ff1732165

running 9 tests
test hash::vec::test_hash_entry::test_get_offset_tombstone ... ok
test hash::vec::test_hash_entry::test_get_offset_value ... ok
test hash::vec::test_hash_table::test_delete ... ok
test hash::vec::test_hash_table::test_delete_and_set ... ok
test hash::vec::test_hash_table::test_get_from_hash ... ok
test hash::vec::test_hash_table::test_get_non_existant_from_hash ... ok
test hash::vec::test_hash_table::test_override ... ok
test hash::vec::test_hash_table::test_grow_hash ... ok
test hash::vec::test_hash_table::test_set_after_filled_with_tombstones ... ok

test result: ok. 9 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 8 filtered out
```

When I try to run `target/debug/deps/ox-824a031ff1732165`, it runs all my tests, not just the 9 specified in `hash::vec`.

I've tried to run `cargo rustc --test hash::vec` but I get
`error: no test target named`hash::vec`.`cargo rustc -- --test`works, but creates a binary that runs all tests. If I try`cargo rustc -- --test hash::vec`, I get:

```
   Compiling ox v0.1.0 (file:///ox)
error: multiple input filenames provided

error: Could not compile `ox`.
```

`cargo rustc -h` says that you can pass NAME with the `--test` flag (`--test NAME              Build only the specified test target`), so I'm wondering what "NAME" is and how to pass it in so I get a binary that only runs the specified 9 tests in `hash::vec`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, at least not directly.

In the case of `cargo test hash::vec`, the `hash::vec` is just a substring matched against the full path of each test function *when the test runner is executed*.  That is, it has absolutely no impact whatsoever on which tests get compiled, only on which tests run.  In fact, this parameter is passed to the test runner itself; Cargo doesn't even interpret it itself.

In the case of `--test NAME`, `NAME` is the name of the test *source*.  As in, passing `--test blah` tells Cargo to build and run the tests in `tests/blah.rs`.  It's the same sort of argument as `--bin NAME` (for `src/bin/NAME.rs`) and `--example NAME` (for `examples/NAME.rs`).

If you really want to only compile a particular subset of tests, the only way I can think of is to use conditional compilation via features.  You'd need a package feature for each subset of tests you want to be able to enable/disable.

Comment: Ah okay, that actually answers my question. All I really needed to do was run my subset of tests (I'm trying to run valgrind to detect memory leaks). Passing hash::vec to the binary did exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

This functionality has found its way into Cargo. `cargo build` now has a parameter

```
 --test [<NAME>]           Build only the specified test target
```

which builds a binary with the specified set of tests only.